# Deploying a JavaFX application onto a J2ME handset

Tags: netbeans, mobile, javafx

I've generated a barely minimal JavaFX (1.2) app, using Netbeans 6.7.1.

Now I have come to put the app on a) an emulator b) a device.

I can't seem to find anywhere in the tooling which will help me do either.

- what am I missing/doing wrong
- any thoughts on a very easy handset to get up and running?

Answer (score 2):

JavaFX Mobile apps do not run on stock J2ME devices. You need a device with JavaFX support. Right now the only option is to install the Developer Stack (download [here](http://javafx.com/downloads/all.jsp)) on a Windows Mobile device (only supported right now is HTC Diamond).

Comment: Thanks. When reading the docs, I had taken it to mean that there were lots out there, but there was also an early access to the WinMo phones too. WinMo the first and only...